# undefined control sequences in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I'm trying to set up an environment where I can write slides and then recompile as an article. I'm using `beamerarticle` with a pair of stubs (one for `beamer` and one for `beamerarticle`) that look like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\input{CS301-lecture-style.tex}
\input{CS301-01-review-lecture-body.tex}
```

As I understand it, `beamerarticle` should ignore beamer-specific stuff that doesn't apply to an article, but I am getting "undefined control sequence" errors for several commands that work in beamer, such as `\insertpagenumber`.  Strangely, `\insertframenumber` does not throw an error, but `\inserttotalframenumber` does.

These errors are concentrated primarily on my definition of the footer line for my slides:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}
\dbgCourseNumber\ 
\insertshortauthor\hfill
\insertshorttitle\hfill
\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}
  }
```

Interestingly, this sequence throws another error (missing \begin{document}) if it appears before `\begin{document}` in `beamerarticle`, but works OK in the preamble of beamer.  This is frustrating because I want to separate these style setup commands in a separate document that can be applied to all lectures.

Any help would be appreciated, specifically, how do I know what will work in `beamerarticle` and what will not.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally beamer specific settings, which don't really make sense in an article, are only defined for all presentation modes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<presentation>{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \vspace*{-8pt}%
            %\dbgCourseNumber\ 
            \insertshortauthor\hfill%
            \insertshorttitle\hfill%
            \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber%
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the same way, you can use `\mode<article>{...}` to modify the footline in a way that is compatible with the article document class.